# Cannot get Laravel Passport to work with Vapor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-vapor

Following Passport's instructions, since I cannot store public/private keys in a storage directory for Vapor, I use the following command to publish the `passport.php` configuration file, as per their instructions:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config
```

This enables me to set environment variables `PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY` and `PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY`, so I can use them with Vapor since Vapor doesn't have any filesystem. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error:

> Unable to read key from file file:///var/www/html/storage/oauth-public.key

Even though I told it to use environment variables, it still tries to find the file. Is there a way to force it to check the `.env` file instead? I am currently doing this locally to see how/if it will work in production.

Comment: I tried with " vapor secret:passport production " but not worked. Secrets are created but same errors are there.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

- You may easily add your project's Passport keys as secrets using the `secret:passport` CLI command:
  `vapor secret:passport production`
- Rerun your deployment pipeline

Reference: *[Passport Keys](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#passport-keys)*